# jQuery cross domain call to REST service

Tags: jquery, wcf, webservice-client

Trying to get data from a REST WCF service on another domain. Here is the creation of my service which seems to be fine and receives the request with my parameter and the jQuery time stamp function signature.

```
_Service = new WebServiceHost(myObject);
var binding = new WebHttpBinding() { CrossDomainScriptAccessEnabled = true };
var endpoint = _Service.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(myObjectContract), binding, "http://localhost:8000/myObject_Service");
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
            _Service.Open();
```

Here is the jQuery call...

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8000/myObject_Service/GetInterfaceInfo?interfaceId=1&callback=?",
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}).fail(function (data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

I have tried formatting the data a number of ways to get it to be parsed correctly but I either get an error that the callback function "was not called" or that there is a "parsererror". Here is an attempt below, returning a string in the format that people have suggested on other posts, but no data ever comes through.

```
jQuery17106912882712204009_1384296559027({"data":"1","data":"2"})
```

Here is the data that is sent from the service

```
public string GetInterfaceInfo(int interfaceId, string callback)
{
    return new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_I);
    //Tried this below, also with no success.
    //return string.Format("{0}({1})", callback, output);
}
```

I am getting no data back at my ajax call, though it does work though because in a browser call. I get all this data.

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
[{"Id":100,"Status":true,"Direction":"Inbound","Name":"Test_100","Sent":0,"Received":1000,"LastMessage":"2013-11-13 08:50:33.AM","Filtered":0,"CanRestart":true},{"Id":101,"Status":false,"Direction":"Inbound","Name":"Test_101","Sent":0,"Received":1000,"LastMessage":"2013-11-13 08:50:33.AM","Filtered":0,"CanRestart":true},{"Id":102,"Status":true,"Direction":"Inbound","Name":"Test_102","Sent":0,"Received":1000,"LastMessage":"2013-11-13 08:50:33.AM","Filtered":0,"CanRestart":true}]
</string>
```

**What is wrong with my ajax call?**

Comment: to your last three questions, No, no, and no. Are you generating `jQuery17106912882712204009_1384296559027` manually, or is that what jQuery is telling your server to return. So far, everything looks good other than `crossDomain: true`, it isn't needed but shouldn't make your request fail.

Comment: When you get a parseerror, do you open your javascript console to see the responsetext that failed to be parsed?

Comment: Is it returning to your success or fail function? And if inspect the request via Network inspection through the browser, what is the response and response code?

Comment: It is returning to the fail function. I have not been able to examine the response text. I use the Chrome dev tools to debug scripts. Should I be using another tool that would give me more details about the failure?

Comment: Click the network tab, it will give you all of the information on the request. (don't forget to *click* the request)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was an issue with the attribute in my service contract, it should have been
    **ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json**, though I thought JSON was supposed to be the default type.